# Importar un fichero que se encuentra en Vendor, Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel

he instalado lo siguiente en laravel, este archivo contiene funciones, mi duda es como utilizar estas funciones en el web.php o en un controlador.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado lo siguiente en el web.php y me da este error:

```
namespace Vendor\Pixeloution\Random\Randomizer;

Route::get('/random', function(){

    $generator=integers( 0, 100, 15 );

    return $generator;
});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Prueba  `use Pixeloution\Random\Randomizer;` en vez de `namespace Vendor\Pixeloution\Random\Randomizer;`

Comment: Si también lo probé y me dice "Call to undefined function integers()"

Comment: No conozco ese paquete, pero supongo que tendrías que crear una instancia de esa clase para luego usar sus funciones. Algo así `$generator = new Randomizer('test@example.com'); $generator->integers( 0, 100, 15 );`